# Evaluating a formula defined in another cell

Tags: excel, xlm

Say I've got a function name in cell `A1`, like `SUM`, and some data in `B1` and `C1`. Is there any way to define a formula in one cell such that it calls the formula that is defined in `A1` and have it work on `B1` and `C1` as data?

So something like:
`=A1(B1:C1)` should be equal to `=SUM(B1:C1)` since `A1` contains the word `SUM` in it.

Essentially, something like preprocessor macros in C, or function pointers maybe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it using vba by creating a user defined function in a module:

```
Public Function applyFunction(functionName As Range, argument As Range) As Variant
    applyFunction = Evaluate(functionName & "(" & argument.Address & ")")
End Function
```

If you put `SUM` in A1, and 1, 2, 3 in B1, B2, B3, `=applyFunction(A1,B1:B3)` will return 6. It is equivalent to calling `=SUM(B1:B3)`.

**EDIT**

If you really don't want to use VBA, you can create a name (insert name in excel 2003 I think, Define Name in Excel 2010):

- Define a new name (let's say `eval1`)
- in the refers to area, enter `=EVALUATE(A1&"(B1:B3)")`, where A1 contains SUM and B1:B3 is the range with the numbers
- in a blank cell, type `=eval1` and it should return the result

But this approach is less flexible.

Comment: Very nice, assylias! You beat me to the punch with the VBA function :)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any possible way to do this without using a VBA function? I've been meaning to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @9a3eedi I don't think there is a built-in function that does that. Maybe someone else does. Any specific reasons why you don't want to use VBA?

Comment: @assylias This question is for a friend. I don't think he knows anything about VBA. Guess I'll just have to teach him, shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: In this case it is fairly straigthforward: open the Macro editor, create a new module, copy paste the code and you are done. You can find plenty of tutorials on google if needed. See my edits for a solution without VBA.

Comment: Sounds simple enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a formula instead, you could possibly use the SUBTOTAL() function.  However, it is a little limited.

Check out the image.  It uses the reference to the function number for subtotal.  You can expand this by creating a vlookup function if you want to use the name of the function, but you also have to provide a way to determine to use the regular function num or the 101-type values which ignores hidden values in the data range.

Check out this link for more info:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/subtotal-function-HP010062463.aspx

[image]

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted - it might be a sensible approach depending on the requirement of the OP.

Comment: I have no idea why I got downvoted either.  I thought it was helpful.  This is like the second time in a row.  Makes me not want to post anything anymore :P

Comment: Somebody might think that this is only a partial answer as it does not cover other functions but I don't think it deserves a downvote + it is good practice for downvoters to leave a comment so that answers can be deleted if really wrong or improved if they are partially wrong. Keep posting and don't forget that a downvote is -2 vs. an upvote +10 ;)

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement, assylias! I'm still learning the etiquette around here so your comments help me out a lot. I'll keep at it :)